# Batch Sorting System

Tags: sorting, batch-file, system, winrar

So my batch file is supposed to do this:

I have a few hundred WinRAR generated "(NAME).part???.rar" files that i want to put into a generated folder tree.

It should put the first 10 files (from 001 to 010) into a new folder named 001 (not just 1).
Then it takes the next ten (011-020) and put them into 002.

I i have fixed everything with adding the zeros automaticly, and i tested all variables but i can't get the actual file movement to work.

Here is what i'm trying to execute:

```
move "%FILENAME%" %LOOP2%\
```

**%LOOP2%** and is just the var %LOOP% (which starts at 1 and goes +1 every tenth loop) with all needed zeros in front of it (so 007, 035 and 455 etc.).

**%FILENAME%** comes from some more variables:

```
set FILENAME=%NAME%.part%COUNT2%.rar
```

**%NAME%** holds the name of the file/files/filepack (?) i want to move,
e.g. "Splitted file.part001.rar" would be "Splitted file"
(entered by user)

**%COUNT2%** starts at 1 and increases every loop until it matches the user-entered %NUMBER% var, which is the last file number (e.g. 468). It comes from %COUNT% which i don't want to change, so i created %COUNT2%.

I tried almost everything but sometimes cmd tells me the file or directory wasn't found or it suddenly closes displaying something with "can't syntacticly be used here" for a brief moment.
(Also the message is translated from German!)

People talk lot about putting double percent signs or double quotes or no quotes and so on and i tried most combinations but still i can't get it to work.
Can someone give me the right syntax and tell me where and how i have to use quotes and double percent signs?

I know my code and this text is pretty messy but i'm still learning :)
Ofc i asked Dr. Google and Stackoverflow but i think my case is a bit specific.

Comment: It's likely that the user entered value `"Splitted file"` that is being added to the `FILENAME` variable looks like this `"Splitted file".part001.rar`, which is not correct.  It should look like this `"Splitted file.part001.rar"`.  Have you tried echoing the `FILENAME` var and then pausing before the `move` command to see what it actually looks like?

Comment: You can remove the quotes from `%NAME%` like this `set NAME=%NAME:"=%`, then you can put the quotes around the whole filename `set FILENAME="%NAME%.part%COUNT2%.rar"`.

Comment: i checked the qoutes before, echoing %FILENAME% outputs without any...

Comment: i also tried everything in an user-input cmd by entering the important  lines step by step and it worked. i know that some things are different for batch files but i cant figure out what it is

Comment: Have you tried placing `echo` before the `move` command so you can see what the OS is trying to execute when it says you have a syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown your code and there is no way to guess what the problem is, so I created my own:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "NAME=Enter name of file/files/filepack (NO quotes): "
set /P "NUMBER=Enter number of files to copy: "

set /A COUNT2=1000, LOOP2=1000
for /L %%i in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
   set /A COUNT2+=1, COUNT2mod10=COUNT2 %% 10
   if !COUNT2mod10! equ 1 (
      set /A LOOP2+=1
      md !LOOP2:~1!
   )
   move "%NAME%.part!COUNT2:~1!.rar" !LOOP2:~1!
)
```

Comment: i thought the rest of the code wasnt that important and its VERY messy! also i didnt use any FOR because i couldnt get it to work.

Comment: okay the code worked perfectly - thank you very much - but i'd like to at least understand the code when i didnt wrote it myself:

   set /A COUNT2+=1, COUNT2mod10=COUNT2 %% 10

why COUNT2mod10 ? and what means "%% 10"? :D
also i think i know that an exclamation mark means inversion but why before and after the var? and why no percent signs?
im sorry i am a real beginner and i have no clue about how these exclamation marks are used here ^^'
sorry again but thanks for the code!

Comment: `%% 10` in a `set /a` statement returns the remainder after dividing by 10.  `!variablename!` is the same as `%variablename%` but when using delayed expansion it allows you to change and use a variable within a loop.  `COUNT2mod10` is just a descriptive variable name.